# Find all possible combinations of tuple pairs merging each into new sequences

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-2.7, combinations

I have a bus route that travels on a route (sequence of places) in this order:-

```
Ayr - Newton - Troon - Paisley - Glasgow
```

i.e `route = ['Ayr', 'Newton', 'Troon', 'Paisley', 'Glasgow']`

I needed to find every possible way you can split the journey up (always starting at Ayr ending at Glasgow so I have code (python) that finds every pair combination and appends each (tuple) pair to a list.

```
pairs = [('Ayr', 'Newton'),('Ayr', 'Troon'),('Ayr', 'Paisley'),('Ayr', 'Glasgow'),('Newton', 'Troon'),('Newton', 'Paisley'),('Newton', 'Glasgow'),('Troon', 'Paisley'),('Troon', 'Glasgow'),('Paisley', 'Glasgow')]
```

What I want to end up with is a list of lists or list of tuples (or the fastest most memory efficient sequence) that has every possible combination of pairs (that starts in Ayr and ends in Glasgow).

```
final_splits = [['Ayr', 'Glasgow'], ['Ayr', 'Newton', 'Glasgow'], ['Ayr', 'Newton', 'Troon', 'Glasgow'], ['Ayr', 'Newton', 'Troon', 'Paisley', 'Glasgow'], ['Ayr', 'Troon', 'Glasgow'], ['Ayr', 'Troon', 'Glasgow'], ['Ayr', 'Troon', 'Paisley', 'Glasgow']..........etc]
```

Not an easy one! Can anyone help?

Comment: Shouldn't it be Prestwick between Ayr and Troon?

Comment: Ah a comedian! Yes this bus route is missing a few stops!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming every combination would appear in pairs, there is no need to compute that intermediate step

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> route = ['Ayr', 'Newton', 'Troon', 'Paisley', 'Glasgow']
>>> [(route[0],)+x+(route[-1],) for i in range(len(route)-1) for x in combinations(route[1:-1],i)]
[('Ayr', 'Glasgow'), ('Ayr', 'Newton', 'Glasgow'), ('Ayr', 'Troon', 'Glasgow'), ('Ayr', 'Paisley', 'Glasgow'), ('Ayr', 'Newton', 'Troon', 'Glasgow'), ('Ayr', 'Newton', 'Paisley', 'Glasgow'), ('Ayr', 'Troon', 'Paisley', 'Glasgow'), ('Ayr', 'Newton', 'Troon', 'Paisley', 'Glasgow')]
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you so much. Losing the intermediate step rocks too

Comment: Actually, I've just realised I need the intermediate step sometimes. How do I generate the final result from the pairs?

Comment: @Handloomweaver, does that mean that not every possible combination is in the pairs?

Comment: I'm being an idiot. By using combinations I can get the pairs I need anytime anyway: e.g [pair for pair in combinations(route, 2)] Thanks everyone